# PHP readfile returns zero length file

Tags: php, readfile

This is **weird**.

I have a script which sends local zip files to the user via browser. The script has worked fine so far without any problems. Today my colleague notified me about the script is sending zero-length files.

Some background info:

- Server settings has not been modified before the script went wrong
- Different browsers tested (same on Chrome/Firefox)
- Previous zip files (which worked fine before) are zero-length too
- Script founds the files on the server
- File size (when echoed for debugging) is correct
- Tried to tweak server settings and script as [adviced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946791/php-readfile-and-large-downloads) with no success.

**UPDATES:**

- `is_readable()` returns 1
- file sizes may vary between 5Mb and 100Mb (not specific)
- `$zip_file` holds the file path
- `$zip_name` holds the zip name
- file is really zero-length (opened in text-editor it doesn't contain a single byte)
- `error_reporting` is `On` (`E_ALL`) shows nothing
- without headers the browser displays the zip 'source' correctly
- Safari says: '**0 bytes of? cannot decode raw data**' first useful(?) symptom

Snippet in question:

```
if (file_exists($zip_file)) {
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: filename="' . $zip_name . '"');
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($zip_file));
    readfile($zip_file);
    exit();
}
```

How can i debug this easily?

Thanks in advance, fabrik

Comment: Stupid question: does the file exist?

Comment: you might want to use `is_readable()` instead of `file_exists()`. is_readable checks whether the file exists and is readable.

Comment: Are they zero-length, or very small-length? In the latter case, they may contain a PHP error message. Just fetch the file and open it with a text editor

Comment: @TGOD Please read my question attentively: "Script founds the files on the server"

Comment: @JohnP, @Unicron just updated my question in response your tips. Thank you.

Comment: @fabrik: ok good, but we can't see the rest of the code can we? Maybe there was a bug that allowed a non-existing file slip through or something like that.

Comment: What is the difference between `$zip_file` and `$zip_name`?

Comment: @TGOD when i printing some debug infos inside `if` it prints nicely. File found, size correct but the resulted file has zero-length.

Comment: @fabrik it's really, literally zero length? Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: What happens when you get the contents of the file, store it in a variable and just echo it out without the headers? Does it print out anything?

Comment: @JohnP a hundred megabyte variable?

Comment: @fabrik, yikes! missed the filesize bit! Looking at the notes on the manual entry : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php you might want to try clearing your buffer or switching to a chunked method

Comment: @JohnP  No prob :) Also as i linked in my question, i've tried to make use of output buffering with no success :(

Comment: @fabrik check whether the first chunk comes through. You could run Xdebug on Eclipse to see where exactly the problem is

Comment: @JohnP echoing the file directly to the browser window is working 'fine'. It seems something happening with the headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My. Lame. Fault.** Sorry for everyone.

Just tweaked the code a week ago and added:

```
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) {
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
} else {
    ob_start();
}
```

What caused this anomaly. :(

Comment: What did you do to solve it? Did you just remove the ob_gzhandler callback?

Answer (score 5):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#102137 :

> It should be noted that in the example:
>
> `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));`
>
> $file should really be the full path to the file.  Otherwise content length will not always be set, often resulting in the dreaded "0 byte file" problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but if i'm echoing the file size it gives me the correct value.

Comment: does not matter, when the browser starts receiving the file the only way f9or it to know the full size is via the headers.

Comment: @Robert i mean echoing for debugging.

Comment: Remove `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));` for debugging.

Comment: oh Thom, you saved my day. Most 0 bytes problem found in SO questions are due to the fact that people mistakenly set filesize($file) while $file is just a handle. HERE $file should be full path to the file. I set it like this header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filePath)); and it worked immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue here I think is the way your sending the file, have you tried sending in within chunks:

```
if (file_exists($zip_file))
{
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: filename="' . $zip_name . '"');
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($zip_file));

    $resource = fopen($zip_file,'r');
    while(!feof($resource))
    {
         $chunk = fread($resource,4096);
         //....
         echo $chunk;
    }

    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it doesn't helped me in any way. Btw when everything will be fine, i'll implement your solution. +1

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: Here is working solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/4706104/ . remove `sleep(1);` for fast download

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `attachment;` and use a different browser.

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . $zip_name . '"');
```

Comment: Look my own answer. It was totally my fault, sorry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375143/php-readfile-returns-zero-length-file/5375762#5375762