# Writing into txt file return empty on IE

Tags: php, readfile

I have a code that save the data of a form into a TXT file and it seems like Internet Explorer can't read the file once it is closed.

The file is successfully saved in my folder and when I load it from the FTP I can see my values, but when I do readfile() on the "submit", the donwloadable file is empty from data.

Here is my code :

```
$fp = fopen("plan_de_concepts/". $nom_du_fichier, "w");
$savestring = "$sujet=*|*=$concept1=*|*=$concept2=*|*=$concept3=*|*=$c1mc1=*|*=$c1mc2=*|*=$c1mc3=*|*=$c1mc4=*|*=$c1mc5=*|*=$c2mc1=*|*=$c2mc2=*|*=$c2mc3=*|*=$c2mc4=*|*=$c2mc5=*|*=$c3mc1=*|*=$c3mc2=*|*=$c3mc4=*|*=$c3mc5=*|*=$c4mc1=*|*=$c4mc2=*|*=$c4mc3=*|*=$c4mc5=*|*=$c5mc1=*|*=$c5mc2=*|*=$c5mc3=*|*=$c5mc3=*|*=$c5mc4=*|*=$c5mc5=*|*=$c6mc1=*|*=$c6mc2=*|*=$c6mc3=*|*=$c6mc4=*|*=$c6mc5";
fwrite($fp, $savestring);
fclose($fp);

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Length: ". filesize($nom_du_fichier));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $nom_du_fichier);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");



readfile('plan_de_concepts/'.$nom_du_fichier);
```

Works great on Firefox and Chrome but IE return empty.. Is there any ways I could force to donwload the "uploaded" version of the file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP readfile returns zero length file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375143/php-readfile-returns-zero-length-file)

Answer (score 2):

You use `filesize($nom_du_fichier)` and `readfile('plan_de_concepts/'.$nom_du_fichier)` (note the folder-prefix). I expect only one of the files exists.

It looks like IE is actually using the Content-Length-header where FF is silently ignoring it.

Comment: You just post the anwser as I found the same thing in SO. Thx buddy.

Answer (score 0):

My Content-length was different of the file exact path. Internet Explorer could not find the file to read it.

> It should be noted that in the example:
>
> header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
>
> $file should really be the full path to the file. **Otherwise content
>   length will not always be set, often resulting in the dreaded "0 byte
>   file" problem.**

Source : [PHP readfile returns zero length file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375143/php-readfile-returns-zero-length-file#answer-5375244)